# How to find time it takes to heat centre of a sphere to a certain temperature?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, thermal-conduction

I'm a high school senior planning a mathematical exploration project where I am aiming to answer the question: I have a spherical ball of dough, which is uniformly at temperature 25 degrees Celsius. I put it in the oven at 200 degrees Celsius. Assuming that the thermal conductivity of the dough is consistent all throughout, how long does it take to heat the centre of the sphere to 80 degrees Celsius?

I've done some preliminary research so far and these are my ideas so far:

- Using the heat equation. (I'm trying to avoid this one because it involved partial differential equations which are probably too advanced for this level)
- Using Fourier's law to find out the heat transfer rate in 1 dimension across 1 sector of the sphere (a long cylindrical piece from the surface to the centre) and then adding these bits together to find total heat energy being transferred to the centre from all sides.
- Using a 2D version of Fourier's law (does this exist?) to find heat transfer rate per unit surface area then adding up heat transfer from each infinitesimal layer of the sphere.
- Newton's law of cooling. From my understanding, this only works for a uniformly heated object, which is why I don't think it is possible to use it here, but I might be misunderstanding it.

The main question is, what would be an approach that could provide a reasonable estimation of the time required? It does not have the be exact, so I don't think something like the heat equation is necessary. If it helps, I am comfortable with calculus up to ODE's, but I haven't mastered PDE's yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure but can you not use heat conduction + Newton's law of cooling, I might be wrong??

Comment: Heat Transmission by McAdams has graphs you can use.

Comment: Separable PDEs should be a comfortable next step after grasping ODEs. Just do the heat equation and find exactly how the interior warms.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually really hard if you want to solve it exactly, but if you want an approximate you can probably use the [Lumped-element model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumped-element_model). It is used to model nonstationary heat flow, but disregarding the spatial coordinates in the heat equation.

So as a solution you would get some temperature function, as a function only on time

$$\vartheta(t)=f.$$

You start, of course, from the first law of thermodynamics:

$$\delta Q=-dU$$

the heat that a body gives away results in a decrease of its internal energy.

Next, we use the [Newton law of cooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_cooling):

$$\Phi=\alpha A_s (\vartheta(t)-\vartheta_\infty)$$

where $\Phi$ is the heat flux is through surface area $A_s$ in some infinitesimal time $dt$ and $\alpha$ is the heat transfer coefficient. The temperature of interest is $\vartheta (t)$ and the temperature away from the boundary (assumed constant) is $\vartheta_\infty$.

Also we know that $dU=\rho V c d\vartheta$.

Combining we get a differential equation:

$$\rho V c d\vartheta=-\alpha A_s (\vartheta(t)-\vartheta_\infty)dt$$

Solving, with the initial value condition $\vartheta=\vartheta_P$, you would get:

$$exp\left(\frac{-t}{\tau}\right)=\frac{\vartheta-\vartheta_\infty}{\vartheta_P-\vartheta_\infty}$$

If we want a function of time, we would transform into:

$$\frac{\vartheta(t)}{dt}=-Bi \frac{a}{l_o^2}(\vartheta_P-\vartheta_\infty )exp\left(-BiFo\right)\tag1$$

Where $Bi$ and $Fo$ are two dimensionless numbers:

$$Bi=\frac{\alpha l_0}{\lambda}$$

where $l_0=\frac{r}{3}$ if you are modelling a sphere, and $\lambda$ is the coefficient of material's conductivity

and

$$Fo=\frac{at}{l_0^2}$$

is the Fourier number and $a=\frac{\lambda}{\rho c}$.

So basically, if you solve $(1)$, you would get the amount of time it takes to heat up (or cool down) some body.

As you can see, it is really hard because you have to know all those coefficients of heat transfer, heat capacities, initial conditions and so on...
The equation $(1)$ might be a good starting point, though. :)